# html css for the value of an input field

Tags: html, css, input, vertical-alignment

I have an input field:

```
 <input type="text" class="form-textbox" id="input_16" name="q16_yourStory16" size="300" value="Your Story" />
```

The value inside is "Your Story" and it is currently vertically centred, and i would like it to be at the top of the box not in the center.

a screen shot is here: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0a34ajx54

I only see a text-align: left in the css, so I am not sure why it is aligning vertically centered?

CSS:

```
#input_16 {
height: 200px;
padding: 10px;
color: #66625F;
text-align: left;
vertical-align: top;
width: 400px;
border: 1px solid #B6D5D7;
padding: 0 5px !important;
}
```

Comment: some css would help, or a working example, more than just a screenshot.  Also, dont use the size attribute, use CSS to style the width and height instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `<textarea>` if you want a multiple line text input area, with the text positioned at the top left. `<input type=text>` is a single line input element, which is why your text is centered

```
<textarea name="q16_yourStory16" id="input_16">Your Story</textarea>

​#input_16 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the input field content will correctly align the text you put in the input field vertically aligned to the top.

what you probably mean is to align the input element within the div or whereever it exists. check the element that contains the input you are looking at and add the vertical-align:top to that style or class.

Comment: I think he was clearly talking about the positioning of the text inside the box. "The value inside is "Your Story" and it is currently vertically centred, and i would like [the text] to be at the top of the box"

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is a text field and not textarea.   What you are wanting is not possible... even with pseudo elements.  sorry